# Finding UK immigration record for Isaac Gabriel of Russia?

Tags: immigration, united-kingdom, london, 1870s, 1860s

I have located Isaac in the 1871 census, 29 years old and resident in London. He was not included in the 1861 census so I have concluded that he arrived in uk sometime between 1861and 1871. He became a British subject in 1881 aged 29 years. I can find no immigration records for Isaac.

How can I find out when he arrived here?

I believe he lived in a place called "Walyraterlel"perhaps in what was then known as Prussia.

Answer (score 5):

There are naturalisation case papers at The National Archives for an Isaac Gabriel of Woolwich dated 1882 which seem likely to be for the same man.

Those should give some background about him and his birthplace/parents:

- [Nationality and Naturalisation: Isaac Gabriel. From Russia. Resident in Woolwich....](http://discovery.nationalarchives.gov.uk/details/r/C4135607) TNA reference - HO 144/94/A13526
- [Naturalisation Certificate: Isaac Gabriel. From Russia. Resident in Woolwich....](http://discovery.nationalarchives.gov.uk/details/r/C11735363) TNA reference - HO 334/10/3639

Comment: I now have these papers in my possessions now know Isaac came from Warsaw but there is no mention of his parents or his past.